# Multiple List values comparison Java

Tags: java, list, sorting

I have two lists.
One contains the history and other the current records.
I want to sort on the basis of sn(first field) and lpn(second field).
In the list below, the first two records are current and next one is history.
I need to sort on the first two fields in a way that current record comes first and then history record.

- 34  0001010 INDIV   06/17/1999  AA  11/19/2015 03:56:52 PM
- 34  0011160 INDIV   06/17/1999  AA  11/19/2015 03:56:52 PM
- 34  0001010         12/07/2016  VV  12/07/2016 02:06:14 PM

Please suggest. TIA.

Code snippet:

```
public class ResultsDTO extends BaseDTO implements Comparable <ResultsDTO> {

    private String sNumber;
    private String lpNumber; 
    private String startDate;  
    private String endDate; 
    private String reason;
}
```

Expected result should be like:

- 34 0001010 INDIV 06/17/1999 AA 11/19/2015 03:56:52 PM
- 34 0001010       12/07/2016 VV 12/07/2016 02:06:14 PM
- 34 0011160 INDIV 06/17/1999 AA 11/19/2015 03:56:52 PM

Comment: Can you paste the code you've tried? Also some code snippet of how your class looks like and how is the data stored currently in the 2 lists?

Comment: So what is the expected output for the input that you provided and your saying 2 lists will contain Objects of type ResultsDTO which needs to be sorted based on their Snumber followed by lpNumber. Correct?

Comment: Does the updated code makes sense?

Comment: I am nit getting the idea on how to combine those fields together and then combine the results. I can't merge the list since on UI current and history records are shown differently..

Comment: is it guaranteed that the AA is history and VV is current? or vice versa?

Answer (score 0):

You have phrased your problem incorrectly.  Here is what you actually need to do:

1. Sort a list of current entries.
2. Sort a list of history entries.
3. Merge these lists such that entries from the current list which match entries from the history list are placed in front of entries from the history list.

This is not only the correct problem statement, it is also the technique you should use to solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks. I was actually meant to mention that I am unable to put my problem correctly..

Comment: Create something to compare a current entry to a history entry.  If the current entry is greater than or equal to the history entry, add it to the merged list.  If the history entry is greater than the current entry, add it to the list.

Comment: I added a flag to keep track if it is current record or history record and then merge the results and sort.